# Data passed between ViewControllers and being Reset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm simply trying to pass an `NSInteger` between 2 `UIViewController` and for some reason, the data keeps getting reset. What I mean by reset is as I do the following:

```
- (void)pickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item
{
    PlayViewController *playScreen = [[PlayViewController alloc] init];
    playScreen.playerNumber = item;
    NSLog(@"%d", playScreen.playerNumber);  
}
```

The NSLog would then print out whatever the index of the chosen object is but once I go to PlayViewController and do the following switch statement:

```
switch (self.playerNumber){
        case 0:
            theView.playerComment.text = @"You, again";
            playerScores[0]++;
            break;

        case 1:
            if (numberPressed % 2){
                theView.playerComment.text = @"Player 2's Turn";
                playerScores[0]++;
            }
            else {
                theView.playerComment.text = @"Player 1's Turn";
                playerScores[1]++;
            }
            break;
 and so on.... the code would always receive 0 as the value of playerNumber...
```

Also, in PlayViewController.h, the variable player number is declared as such:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger playerNumber;
```

Comment: In pickerView you create a new PlayViewController, set playerNumber, then discard that view controller.  Why would you expect the playerNumber value to magically jump to another instance of PlayViewController???

Comment: I think what Hot Licks is trying to say is that the problem is that you're creating a new instance of the `PlayViewController` by writing `PlayViewController *playScreen = [[PlayViewController alloc] init];`, but you never actually transition to that specific instance of that view controller. At the end of your `pickerView:didSelectItem:` that instance you've created disappears and whenever you actually make the transition, it's done using a whole new instance for which `playerNumber` has never been set.

Comment: Create global object of PlayViewController then try it may helps you

Comment: @Nikunj: welcome to [so]. When editing, please try to improve the post as much as you can so others don't have to edit the post more. Also, please [don't use inline code spans (`like this`) for emphasis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135113/220428). Take a look at the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and the [tour]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property of the `PlayViewController` and modify your `pickerView didSelectItem:` delegate.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PlayViewController *playScreen;

- (void)pickerView:(AKPickerView *)pickerView didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item
{
    if (nil == self.playScreen)
    {
       self.playScreen = [[PlayViewController alloc] init];
    }

    playScreen.playerNumber = item;
    NSLog(@"%d", playScreen.playerNumber);  
}
```

Comment: I tried it and called the player number variable in in playviewcontroller by doing the following: **PlayersViewController *players = [[PlayersViewController alloc] init];
    switch (players.playScreen.playerNumber){
        case 0:
            theView.playerComment.text = @"You, again";
            playerScores[0]++;
            break;
            
        case 1:
            if (numberPressed % 2)**

Comment: do not create a new object for 'PlayersViewController' inside the PlayViewController, because you have already have it with datas.

Comment: use the 'playScreen.playerNumber' inside the PlayViewController, modify your switch as switch (self.playerNumber){ case 0: //your code }